# Filament Many To Many Relation Manager , not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, tail, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I have the model Student

Student

- groups : BelongsToMany

and model Group

Group

- students: HasMany

of course there is a pivot table group_student with

group_id
student_id

I am trying, in Filament3, to set up a StudentRelationManager , so that I can add students to a group , with the table (not with select )

I ran this command

```
php artisan make:filament-relation-manager GroupResource students student_id
```

and of course added the relation

```
public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [
            RelationManagers\StudentsRelationManager::class
        ];
    }
```

but the minute a click on edit on a given Group record

I get this
[image]

which is wrong because the student doesnt belong to just one group, but could be in many,
so it doesnt have a group_id, but depends on the pivot table : group_student

Instead of something like this

[image]

What I am missing ? how to make it work ? can this be achieved ? I searched but could nt find other than fixing it with selects .

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

so, the answer wat to use the flags associate

```
 php artisan make:filament-relation-manager GroupResource students student_id --associate
```